# Rewerite URLS .htaccess on host

Tags: .htaccess

I have 3 files: `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cats.php?name=$1
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php
echo 'index';
```

And `cats.php`:

`<?php
echo $_GET['name'] . ' < '.$_GET["name"];`

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm on site.com it redirects me to `cats.php` **always**. But on my localhost it redirects me **only** if an argument is passed e.g.:
`site.com/some-argument`

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that might be causing problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This means execute RewriteRule only if requested file name is **not found**.

On the local host where it is not working you might have following settings in httpd.conf (or .htaccess):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Because of above settings when you enter `http://site.com` then by default `index.php` is attempted to be shown and since it is found by Apache your above RewriteCond returns false and your RewriteRule doesn't fire.

For testing comment out above RewriteCond and see if that changes the behavior.